# Android NPE when changing ImageView from different Layout

Tags: android, imageview, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to change an ImageView in a different layout using code etc:

```
        ImageView imageView;
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wizardhat);
```

But it NPE's on R.drawable.wizardhat because it doesn't know what layout it belongs to, obviously, and it's not in the root layout:

> -main [where both includes are located]
>   -layout1[where code is included]
>   -layout2[where image is located]

EDIT: Ok, I didn't really explain it: The view that the code runs in is inside a tabview. The layout that holds the tab view contains a include to a layout that contains a ImageView which i'm trying to edit. I didn't really word my question correctly, i'll edit it now :L

Is this possible? Thanks :)

Comment: I think you are displaying only one layout at a time, then why are you changing image of another layout?

Comment: In the main screen I have one include (which is the image view i'm editing) and one framelayout (which is the layout that contains the code to change the image)

Comment: So can you put your both layout.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it NPE's on `imageView`, cause before inflating any view you should set its root layout as a content view of your activity. If your `ImageView` belongs to `layout1`, you must be sure that it is the current content view of the activity, then you can inflate it from wherever you want in your code. If `layout1` is not the content view right now, `findViewById()` will return null. I hope I've understood your question properly.

Comment: Ok, I didn't really explain it: The view that the code runs in is inside a tabview. The layout that holds the tab view contains a include to a layout that contains a ImageView which i'm trying to edit. I didn't really word my question correctly, i'll edit it now :L

Answer (score 0):

What I did for my app were:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_grid,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.play_layout_root));
gridview = (GridView)layout.findViewById(R.id.play_gridview);
```

- play_grid is the xml that holds the gridview
- play_layout_root is the root id of this xml layout;
- play_gridview is the id of the gridview I needed.

You could maybe use that for your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I did this:
      ImageView imageButton;
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testpicture,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
   imageButton = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.wizardhat);
   
and it didnt work

Comment: Fail here it is properly:  
Sorry for the late reply, but I did this:  
      `ImageView imageButton;  
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testpicture,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.imageView1));  
   imageButton = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);   
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.wizardhat);`  
   
and it didnt work (EDIT EDIT: how do i do <br/> arwerawgwr)

Comment: You use `inflater.inflate(R.layout.testpicture,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.imageView1));` instead, use this: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.testpicture,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id."the ID of the layout that holds everythings in your testpicture.xml, at the begin"));`